# Does dolphindb have a development plan to support embedded list as a column in a table?

Tags: database, quantitative-finance, dolphindb

Is there any development plan by dolphindb to support embedded list as a column in a table? we need something like the followings:

1. We quickly calculate the cumulative ask/bid qty according to the orderbook and save it to a column.

2. According to the provided qty, we can quickly figure out the corresponding price position on the orderbook and the distance from the price to mid.

A simple example, as shown, in this example only 5 levels in the ask volume, in practice, we have 64-128 profile price and volume.

| av1 | av2 | av3 | av4 | av5 | cav |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | [1,3,6,10,15] |

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB is developing this feature and is expected to be released around the end of October.

Answer (score -1):

array vector, released in 2.00.2
https://www.dolphindb.com/help200/DataTypesandStructures/DataForms/Vector/arrayVector.html